# Nesting multiple tab presenters

Tags: gwt, gwtp

If you consider the GWTP sample app with tabs at:
http://gwtp-sample-tab.appspot.com

Is it possible to have a 3rd level of tabs, lets say inside Home -> Info -> Tab1 and Tab2, and how would that be implemented?

Asked in a different way: it is possible to have nested TabContainerPresenters beyond two levels?

It is important that the 3rd level tabs act as places and that they have their own name tokens.

Comment: Nobody has any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but:

1. When you have 3 levels of nested tabs - managing the code base is like HELL
2. You need to create nav tokens for all combinations of you tabs, and will look like (#tab1lvlTab2lvlTab3lvl), for example if there is 3 tabs in 3 levels, we should create 27 nav tokens, so it's horrible to support

In my opinion - 2 level of nested tabs it's already too much. Maybe you should consider to redesign you navigation in your application.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I agree with you that the design might not be optimal. However, is it possible that you can provide a crude overview of how it would be implemented? I have been trying to extend the gwtp sample app with a 3rd level, but without any luck.